# Finding a closed path from list of start and end nodes

Tags: python, graph, tree, anytree

I have a list of edges (`E`) of a graph with nodes `V = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`:

```
E = [(1,2), (1,5), (2,3), (3,1), (5,6), (6,1)]
```

where each tuple `(a,b)` refers to the start & end node of the edge respectively.

If I know the edges form a closed path in graph G, can I recover the path?

Note that `E` is not the set of all edges of the graph. Its just a set of edges.

In this example, the path would be `1->2->3->1->5->6->1`

A naive approach, I can think of is using a tree where I start with a node, say `1`, then I look at all tuples that start with `1`, here, `(1,2)` and `(1,5)`. Then I have two branches, and with nodes as `2` & `5`, I continue the process till I end at the starting node at a branch.

How to code this efficiently in python?

Comment: Are you looking for a cycle in the graph? Also, do these represent directed or undirected edges?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Yes, The path would be a cycle. I am not "looking" for cycles in a graph. I just have the set E & I want to extract the path from it. Note that E is NOT the set of all edges of the graph. The graph is directed.

Comment: Could the list represent 1->5->6->1->2->3->1? Why or why not? Do you just need one possible closed path?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Yes. Note that these are necessarily the same cycle. Any one suffices.

Comment: why not using https://networkx.org/

Comment: @David is there any function in networkx for that?

Comment: I don't know for sure. I just see that module recently and not play with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The networkx package has a function that can generate the desired circuit for you in linear time...

It is possible, that construction of `nx.MultiDiGraph()` is slower and not such efficient, as desired in question, or usage of external packages for only one function is rather excessive. If it is so, there is another way.

Plan: firstly we will find some way from `start_node` to `start_node`, then we will insert all loops, that were not visited yet.

```py
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict, deque
from typing import Tuple, List, Iterable, Iterator, DefaultDict, Deque


def retrieve_closed_path(arcs: List[Tuple[int, int]], start_node: int = 1) -> Iterator[int]:
    if not arcs:
        return iter([])

    # for each node `u` carries queue of its
    # neighbours to be visited from node `u`
    d: DefaultDict[int, Deque[int]] = defaultdict(deque)
    for u, v in arcs:
        # deque pop and append complexity is O(1)
        d[u].append(v)

    def _dfs(node) -> Iterator[int]:
        out: Iterator[int] = iter([])
        # guarantee, that all queues
        # will be emptied at the end
        while d[node]:
            # chain returns an iterator and helps to
            # avoid unnecessary memory reallocations
            out = chain([node], _dfs(d[node].pop()), out)
            # if we return in this loop from recursive call, then
            # `out` already carries some (node, ...) and we need
            # only to insert all other loops which start at `node`
        return out

    return chain(_dfs(start_node), [start_node])


def path_to_string(path: Iterable[int]) -> str:
    return '->'.join(str(x) for x in path)
```

Examples:

```py
    E = [(1, 2), (2, 1)]
    p = retrieve_closed_path(E, 1)
    print(path_to_string(p))
    >> 1->2->1

    E = [(1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 1), (5, 6), (6, 1)]
    p = retrieve_closed_path(E, 1)
    print(path_to_string(p))

    >> 1->5->6->1->2->3->1

    E = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 2), (2, 1)]
    p = retrieve_closed_path(E, 1)
    print(path_to_string(p))

    >> 1->2->3->4->2->1


    E = [(5, 1), (1, 5), (5, 2), (2, 5), (5, 1), (1, 4), (4, 5)]
    p = retrieve_closed_path(E, 1)
    print(path_to_string())
    >> 1->4->5->1->5->2->5->1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [directed Eulerian circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) in your (sub)graph. An Eulerian circuit is a trail that visits every edge exactly once.

The `networkx` package has a function that can generate the desired circuit for you in linear time:

```py
import networkx as nx

edges = [(1,2), (1,5), (2,3), (3,1), (5,6), (6,1)]
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)

# Prints [(1, 5), (5, 6), (6, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1)]
# which matches the desired output (as asked in the comments).
print([edge for edge in nx.algorithms.euler.eulerian_circuit(G)])
```

The [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.euler.eulerian_circuit.html#id1) cites a 1973 paper, if you're interested in understanding how the algorithm works. You can also take a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/1cf78f7a76772dbb3a8c8c32e09d1032aebba3ea/networkx/algorithms/euler.py#L136). Note that we're working with multigraphs here, since you can have multiple edges that have the same source and destination node. There are probably other implementations floating around on the Internet, but they may or may not work for multigraphs.

Comment: This works only if the (sub)graph is Eulerian. Consider E = [(5,1),(1,5),(5,2),(2,5),(5.1),(1,4),(4,5)] . Here (5,1) is repeated.

Comment: You said that you knew the edges formed a closed path (or really, a closed walk). If we treat repeated edges as separate (i.e. making the graph a multigraph), then this isn't an issue.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by separate? The example I gave above is indeed closed. How do I deal with that?

Comment: In your example, (5, 1) appears twice. We construct a graph that contains two edges whose source is node 5 and whose destination is node 1. This is why the code snippet uses a multigraph.